# Why is this telling me my cout and my return are syntax errors?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, syntax-error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int NUM_GAME = 3;

int main ( void )
{

 int score1 = 0;
 int score2 = 0;
 int score3 = 0;
 int total = 0;
 double average = 0;
 char repeat;
 string name, dummy;

 //Allow user to run program again
 do
 {
//Resets total to process another game if desired
total = 0;

cout << "\nBowler #1's name: ? ";   //Reads name
getline(cin, name);

   do
   {
     cout << "\nEnter"<<name<<"'s score for each of the following games:";
     cin >> score1;
     cin >> score2;
     cin >> score3;
     if(score1 < 0 || score1 > 300 || score2 < 0 || score2 > 300 || score3 < 0 || score3 > 300 )
       cout << "\n\n*** INVALID SCORE ENTERED! Please try again. ***";
   while(score1 > -1 && score1 < 301 || score2 > -1 && score2 < 301 || score3 > -1 && score3 <         301);
   total = score1 + score2 + score3;
   }

  cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint;

//Calcualtes the average sales for the salesperson
average = total / NUM_GAME;
cout << "\n\nThe bowling average for " << name  << " is " << average << endl << endl;

cout << "\nWould you like to calculate the average for another Game? Y or N ";
cin >> repeat;
getline(cin, dummy);
while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');
}
return 0;
}
```

Please excuse the formatting issues and stuff its rough I know
this is coming up with 2 errors:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cout'
error C2059: syntax error : 'return'
```

like I said it's rough and the solution is probably something extremely obvious but I'm new and I'm still learning the ropes

Comment: Two `do`s should have two according `while`s, syntax: `do{...} while(...);`

Comment: I understand, but this is how my teacher formatted it and said it should be set up, so I don't understand why the do{do{while}while} wouldn't work. I also have not learned why that might not work if this is a test either.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, indent your code better.

Secondly,

```
do
{

    while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');
}
```

is probably not what you want.

Comment: If either of those conditionals are true, you're in for a toasty CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The `do...while` should be

```
do
{
  //code
}while(...);
```

Instead of

```
do
{
  //code
  while(...);
}
```

You have to close its body before the `while`. So modify both your loops and then,the errors will be gone.